# Deleting a file using delete() - Java

Tags: java, file-io

My code makes use of `BufferedReader` to read from a file [main.txt] and `PrintWriter` to write to a another temp [main.temp] file. I close both the streams and yet I was not able to call `delete()` method on the `File` object associated with [main.txt]. Only after calling `System.gc()` after closing both the stream was I able to delete the `File` object.

```
public static boolean delete (String str1, String str2, File FileLoc)
{
    File tempFile = null;
    BufferedReader Reader = null;
    PrintWriter Writer = null;

    try
    {
        tempFile = new File (FileLoc.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");
        Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileLoc));
        Writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        String lsCurrLine = null;

        while((lsCurrLine = Reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // ...
            // ...

            if (true)
            {
                Writer.println(lsCurrLine);
                Writer.flush();
            }
        }

        Reader.close();
        Writer.close();
        System.gc();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException loFileExp)
    {
        System.out.println("\n File not found . Exiting");
        return false;
    }
    catch(IOException loFileExp)
    {
        System.out.println("\n IO Exception while deleting the record. Exiting");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is this reliable? Or is there a better fix?

Comment: @Richard: Can you please suggest ?

Comment: You are not calling `File.delete()` anywhere.  Just naming some arbitrary method `delete` doesn't mean it will actually delete files.  And talk about side effects.  If I find in an API a method named `delete`, I'm going to expect it to, well, delete something, not copy data and create random temporary files.

Comment: @user183717: Where are you calling `File.delete`?

Comment: Ok, after re-reading, I think I can guess as to what your confusion might be.  Yes, the in-memory File object will go out of scope and can be GC'ed at some point after the end of your (poorly-named) method.  This is completely decoupled from the existence of the file on disk.  Call tempFile.delete() somewhere.  And please, for the sake of your maintenance programmer (or yourself in 6 months), name your method sanely.

Comment: @Simon - Thank you for the suggestion. And you really don't have to worry about the method/variable names here. I had to modify all the  code names to post it online. I do have experience working in an IT firm and completely understand the need for naming conventions.

Comment: I had to explicitly deallocate by using <BufferedReader Object> = null and <PrintWriter Object> = null to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user183717 - that code you posted is clearly not all of the relevant code.  For instance, those "..."'s and the fact that `File.delete()` is not actually called in that code.

When a stream object is garbage collected, its finalizer closes the underlying file descriptor.  So, the fact that the delete only works when you added the `System.gc()` call is strong evidence that your code is *somehow* failing to close some stream for the file.  It may well be a different stream object to the one that is opened in the code that you posted.

Properly written stream handling code uses a `finally` block to make sure that streams get closed no matter what.  For example:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you don't follow that pattern or something similar, there's a good chance that there are scenarios where streams don't always get closed.  In your code for example, if one of the `read` or `write` calls threw an exception you'd skip past the statements that closed the streams.

> Is this [i.e. calling `System.gc();`] reliable?

No.

1. The JVM may be configured to ignore your application's `gc()` call.
2. There's no guarantee that the lost stream will be unreachable ... yet.
3. There's no guarantee that calling `System.gc()` will notice that the stream is unreachable.  Hypothetically, the stream object might be tenured, and calling `System.gc()` might only collect the Eden space.
4. Even if the stream is found to be unreachable by the GC, there's no guarantee that the GC will run the finalizer immediately.  Hypothetically, running the finalizers can be deferred ... indefinitely.

> Or is there a better fix ?

Yes.  Fix your application to close its streams properly.

Answer (score 2):

try using java.io.File library. here the simple sample:

```
File f = new File("file path or file name");
f.delete();
```

Comment: `File.delete()` isn't working, that's the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you "close both the streams" you mean the `BufferedReader` and the `PrintWriter`?

You should only need to close the `BufferedReader` before the delete will work, but you also need to close the underlying stream; normally calling `BufferedReader.close()` will do that. It sounds like you *think* you are closing the stream but you aren't actually succeeding.

One problem with your code: you don't close the streams if exceptions occur. It's usually best to close the streams in a `finally` block.

Also, the code you posted doesn't use `File.delete()` anywhere? And what exactly do the `...` lines do - are they re-assinging `Reader` to a new stream by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

try using the apache commons io

http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html

Comment: Yes It doesn't seem to delete the file even after closing all the streams