# File is not Deleting

Tags: java

Am trying to deleting particular file in a folder starting with name TRTHIndicative_.

But files are not deleting,am using below code

```
testMethod(inputDir);
testMethod(outputFile);


private static void testMethod(String dirName){
    File directory = new File(dirName);

    // Get all files in directory
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {

        if (file.getName().startsWith("Indicative_")) {
            // Delete each file
            if(file.exists()){
                System.out.println("File is there!");
            }
            if (file.delete()) {
                // Failed to delete file
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Deleted file succsfully");
            }
        }

    }
```

please check and let me know if anything wrong.

Comment: You have the wrong order in the if-else statement. if file.delete() then the file was deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a file using delete() - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809418/deleting-a-file-using-delete-java)

Comment: dupicate question already asked

Comment: Am asking deleting particular file in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have permission error in the file you try to delete.
elToro`s answer is working fine with me as well.
Try to give read/write permission to every user
[how to change file permissions in windows](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

You have your `if` and `else` confused - `File#delete()` returns `true` if the file is **successfully** deleted. So, the condition should be reversed:

```
if (file.delete()) {
    System.out.println("Deleted file succesfully");
} else {
    // Failed to delete file
    System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mureinik is right.
I just tried your peace of code. It works fine. Just do the changes as follows:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File directory = new File("C:/temp");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {

        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("blub")) {
            // Delete each file
            if (file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File is there!");
            }
            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Deleted file succsfully");
            } else {
                // Failed to delete file
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note the **toLowerCase()** I added. It will make your snippet easier to use.

Comment: thanks for the response! i am getting this error : Failed to delete C:\Data_in\TRTHIndicative_20.txt